# Weird features of Python?

Tags: python

In earlier years, i had find that:

```
# Python code

x = [[0]*5]*5 # IMO, it will be a 5*5 2D-Array-Like
x[2][2] = 2

# I considered x will be
# [
# [0,0,0,0,0],
# [0,0,0,0,0],
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# [0,0,0,0,0],
# [0,0,0,0,0]]

# But x will be
# [
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# [0,0,2,0,0]]
```

So, why?
Of course, later i had known this is because references of inner list.
I do not thinks it is a good idea.

But again:

```
x[:][4] = 4
```

IMO again:

x[:] must be x's self.
x[:][4] must be the last member of x.
So x will be:

```
#[
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# [0,0,2,0,0],
# 4]
```

But it is not, there is no change!

So, why?

And, are there any other wired cases in Python?
Please show below.

I just wanna collect things looks a bit strange in Python, not just a quizzer about this question.

Comment: If this behavior surprises you, you **must** watch [facts and myths about Python names and values](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns).

Comment: Do you know the difference between reference and value? If you don't, that's hard to explain why...